# Who built the shrine of Hilal ibn Ali in Kashan, Iran?

Tags: islam, architecture, iran, persia

The [shrine of Hilal ibn Ali](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hilal%20ibn%20Ali%20in%20Kashan,%20Iran&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0oNDrzuzaAhULZd8KHTDJBdwQsAQILg&biw=1517&bih=693) is an incredible piece of architecture but yet I cannot find any info online about who built it and when!

Comment: It might help people researching your question if you indicate some of the sources you have looked at so far.

Comment: [There is some information posted at the shrine](https://web.archive.org/web/20110720172849/http://www.helal.ir/helal/modules.php?name=Content&pa=showpage&pid=69).  Doesn't answer the question directly, but it may help other research.

Comment: It appears that [nosytourist](http://nosytourist.com/Hilal-ibn-AliShrine) has some of the information; it may be worth your while to contact them directly.

Answer (score 2):

> The construction of this building goes back to the Safavid period (1501-1736) and it has been renovated several times thus far. The interiors of the building are decorated with watercolor paintings. There is a marble plate in the northern balcony just above the entrance which is inscribed with some information about the construction of this monument. There is also a script carved on the wooden front door which provides some information about the person who endowed the door to the holy shrine during the Qajar period, in 1849. *[Kashancht.ir](http://www.kashancht.ir/content_view.aspx?id=120569&c=1&language=en)*